# Render view as string then redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I would like my controller action to render a view to a string, send an email using that string as the body, then do a redirect.

I've found several articles here on SO and elsewhere on how to render the view to a string. That part was easy.

But when I attempt to perform the redirect, I get an HttpException: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent. I've tried setting Response.Buffer and Response.BufferOutput to true, I've tried Response.Clear, nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to render a view to a string, then do a redirect?

Comment: IIRC there are many ways to render a view to a string. Please post a link to the one you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have to end the response to render view to a string.

Have a look [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1193898.aspx) and [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/06/mvc-framework-capturing-output-of-view_05.html) (this one has the exact sample you need).

The last link should be:

```
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/06/mvc-framework-capturing-output-of-view_05.html
```

It seems StackOverflow encodes underscore in the link which causes. Just make sure you have _05.html at the end.
Also if I go to the Address bar in the browser (after the link is clicked), put cursor there and hit enter it works.
It is weird.